# Fetch live data (json) and make accessible to javascript or javascript library (React)

Tags: javascript

I've built a service that returns data from an external API (in JSON format).

I do not want to render that directly onto a page or store it in a node but rather make it accessible to javascript/jquery/React for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Drupal without Drupal knowing anything about it. I have done things like this before in Twig templates:

```
{% if node.field_myfield is not empty %}
  <script>
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "/api/v1/auth/" + {{ node.id }} + '?s=' + Date.now());
    request.responseType = "text";
    request.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("authorize-banner").innerHTML = request.response;
    };
    request.send();
  </script>

  <div id="authorize-banner"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Where `request` is basic JS making a request to the Drupal backend (custom route) which handles the request and assembles the response, which is then written to the div below. Nothing is saved anywhere.

Here is a similar example, again in Twig, but this time there is no backend processing at all, React handles it:

```
<div class="js-search-mountnode" data-id="listing"></div>
<script>
var config = {
    id: 'listing',
    api: '{{ your_url_variable }}',
    type: "listing",
    showCalendar: true,
    showClear: true,
    showNewKey: false,
    showResultsSummary: true,
    dictionary: {
    resultsTitle: "Filter Search",
    facetsTitle: "Filter Search",
    facetsDescription: "Projects in this search date approx 3 years back.",
    searchBoxLabel: "Title, Number or Keyword",
    singleresult: "result",
    pluralresult: "results"
    }
};
window.listingConfigs = window.listingConfigs || [];
window.listingConfigs.config = config;
</script>
```

Without going into a lot of detail, the React component loads and fires a request to the `api` value in the config object (props) attached here, and React generates the entire display within the div as a React component. Again, nothing is stored or saved, both happen on load.

That said, you don't want it to render in a page (but won't it eventually, if its a React component?) - you could just request it directly in Javascript without putting it anywhere else, or from a non-Drupal site by doing the same.

Comment: Nicely done...  I can't request it directly with Javascript because authentication has to happen prior (and that has to be done via 2 legged OAuth2 on the backend). 

So far, I've gotten the data in via Guzzle (using middleware for Oauth2) .  You're examples are usually spot on, I'm guessing that the solution is pretty close to what you've described (though I don't think I can request it directly from the API source with Javascript)

Comment: You can pass credentials in JS - check the XmlHttpRequest docs. it’s an easy pass in jquery too.

Comment: If you have a valid OAuth session or token in a cookie you should be able to pass that... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials  I have not tried it myself.